# Variables or bind variables using field values in Oracle PL/SQL to use with DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle

If I could get this to work at the top of my select statement as a WITH clause that would be even better as this code is reused throughout the query with different pcode combinations.

```
--set a bind variable
VARIABLE pcode VARCHAR(3) --tried a bunch of various syntax with BEGIN/END/DECLARE/DEFINE...etc

--initiate the variable with
:pcode := (field1 || field2 || field 3) -- from my_table ? can't get syntax right here

--next I want to use the variable as follows
SELECT 

--some field variables may be null so that only 1 or 2 characters are returned
DECODE (
    pcode, 'A', amount_field * -1,
    pcode, 'A1A', amount_field * -1,
    pcode, 'A5', 0,
    pcode, 'A6', 0,
    pcode, 'B1', amount_field * -1,
    pcode, 'B5', amount_field * 0,
    pcode, 'B6', 0,
    amount_field -- default
    ) as my_new_column -- set the value for each row in the table

FROM my_table
```

I've tried a ton of combinations of

```
DECLARE
DEFINE
BEGIN END
EXEC
/
SELECT INTO
...etc
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of what you are trying to achieve; and the expected output for that sample data. You state `:pcode := (field1 || field2 || field 3) -- from my_table ?` which doesn't make sense you need a `SELECT` statement to read columns from a table which is why we need a simple English explanation of what you are trying to do because the code is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read columns from a table and for each row concatenate three column values and use that to determine what transformation to apply to a fourth column in that row using `DECODE` then you do not need (or want) to use a bind variable. Just `SELECT` from the table and use `DECODE` directly on the column values.

You only want to use the `pcode` once as the first argument of `DECODE`:

```sql
SELECT field1 || field2 || field3 AS pcode,
       DECODE (
         field1 || field2 || field3,
         'A',   amount_field * -1,
         'A1A', amount_field * -1,
         'A5',  0,
         'A6',  0,
         'B1',  amount_field * -1,
         'B5',  amount_field * 0,
         'B6',  0,
                amount_field -- default
       ) as my_new_column -- set the value for each row in the table
FROM   my_table;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (field1, field2, field3, amount_field) AS
SELECT 'A', NULL, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', '1',  'A',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', '5',  NULL, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', '6',  NULL, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', NULL, '1',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', '5',  NULL, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', '6',  NULL, 7 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PCODE | MY_NEW_COLUMN |
| --- | --- |
| A | -1 |
| A1A | -2 |
| A5 | 0 |
| A6 | 0 |
| B1 | -5 |
| B5 | 0 |
| B6 | 0 |

If you want a `WITH` clause then just wrap it around the query:

```sql
WITH codes (pcode, my_new_column) AS (
  SELECT field1 || field2 || field3 AS pcode,
         DECODE (
           field1 || field2 || field3,
           'A',   amount_field * -1,
           'A1A', amount_field * -1,
           'A5',  0,
           'A6',  0,
           'B1',  amount_field * -1,
           'B5',  amount_field * 0,
           'B6',  0,
                  amount_field
         )
  FROM   my_table
)
SELECT *
FROM   codes;
```

Which outputs the same as the previous.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PR-XP9Bi)

Comment: This is fantastic. I can't believe I had the DECODE syntax all wrong and I overlooked where the expression went. Thank you so much for this it's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question - you have all the data in your database but searching for a way that you can define your new column values once (WITH clause) and use that data throughout your query below.
You probably can create a CTE with all the data needed for further processing.
First some sample data to work with:

```sql
WITH  --  S a m p l e   D a t a : (your actual table or view or ...)
    tbl ( ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, AMOUNT_FIELD ) AS
        ( Select 1, NULL, NULL, 'A',  10 From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 'A', '1',   'A',  15 From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 'A', '5',   NULL,  5 From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 'A', '6',   NULL, 12 From Dual Union All
          Select 5, 'B', '1',   NULL, 17 From Dual Union All
          Select 6, 'B', '5',   NULL,  9 From Dual Union All
          Select 7, 'B', '6',   NULL,  2 From Dual
        ),
```

Next - create CTE that will contain all the columns that you will need either to further process or to join on and generate data for PCODE (concatenated from 3 columns) and PCODE_AMOUNT (calculated as in your DECODE()). Instead of DECODE() I used Case expression - but you can use DECODE() ...

```sql
    pcode_amounts AS    -- a CTE created in WITH clause
        ( Select  ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, AMOUNT_FIELD,
                  FIELD1 || FIELD2 || FIELD3 "PCODE",
                  Case  FIELD1 || FIELD2 || FIELD3
                        When  'A'   Then AMOUNT_FIELD * -1
                        When  'A1A' Then AMOUNT_FIELD * -1
                        When  'A5'  Then 0
                        When  'A6'  Then 0
                        When  'B1'  Then AMOUNT_FIELD * -1
                        When  'B5'  Then AMOUNT_FIELD * 0
                        When  'B6'  Then 0
                Else  AMOUNT_FIELD
                End "PCODE_AMOUNT"
          From  tbl
       -- Where FIELD1 || FIELD2 || FIELD3 IN('A1', 'B1') <--- you can put here the value(s) that you want to filter with (if you want)
                                                            -- or somewhere else ( as PCODE IN('A1', 'B1') ) in the rest of your code
        )
Select  *
From    pcode_amounts
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
            pcode_amounts CTE's RecordSet:
        ID FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 AMOUNT_FIELD PCODE PCODE_AMOUNT
---------- ------ ------ ------ ------------ ----- ------------
         1               A                10 A              -10
         2 A      1      A                15 A1A            -15
         3 A      5                        5 A5               0
         4 A      6                       12 A6               0
         5 B      1                       17 B1             -17
         6 B      5                        9 B5               0
         7 B      6                        2 B6               0   */
```

Finaly, this resulting recordset above could be used further in your processing. You have all the data from database in the same row with PCODE (concatinated) and PCODE_AMOUNT (calculated). You have some ID that could be used in joins, and you have all three individual fields for eventualy needed exception conditionings or whatever else (some other joins/filterings/... maybe)...
This CTE (within scope) acts as a virtual table and anything you do with your other tables in further processing you can do with pcode_amounts too.
**Addition:**
Just something that maybe, just maybe, could be helpfull. Since you concatenate three columns  with possible nulls there are combinations that are different and act the same. If F1 and F2 are null and F3 is 'A' you got 'A'. If F1 is 'A' and F2 and F3 are null you got 'A' again. That is ok, but maybe it could help if you beside the PCODE as is have let's say PCODE_TXT having distinguished values that could be used later as a whole new column or positionaly (position 1 is F1, position 2 is F2, position 3 is F3).
If we add three more rows to your data like here...

```sql
          Select 8, 'B', NULL,   NULL,  100 From Dual Union All
          Select 9, NULL, NULL,  'B',  200 From Dual Union All
          Select 10, 'A', NULL,   NULL, 300 From Dual
```

... and if we add one more column to the pcode_amounts cte's selection list ...

```sql
         Select ...,
                ...,
                Nvl(FIELD1, '*') || Nvl(FIELD2, '*') || Nvl(FIELD3, '*') "PCODE_TXT"
         From   ...
```

... then there will be potentialy usefull column that could be linked or compared or evaluated against all three concatenated columns individualy or could be considered as whole for some other use. Result is here:

```sql
/*
        ID FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 AMOUNT_FIELD PCODE   PCODE_ID PCODE_AMOUNT PCODE_TXT
---------- ------ ------ ------ ------------ ----- ---------- ------------ ---------
         1               A                10 A            1          -10   **A
         2 A           1 A                15 A1A          1          -15   A1A
         3 A           5                   5 A5           1            0   A5*
         4 A           6                  12 A6           1            0   A6*
         5 B           1                  17 B1           1          -17   B1*
         6 B           5                   9 B5           1            0   B5*
         7 B           6                   2 B6           1            0   B6*
         8 B                             100 B            2          100   B**
         9               B               200 B            1          200   **B
        10 A                             300 A            2         -300   A**      */
```

Comment: The previous answer works great, this one works even better. I want to use WITH is because subquery gets reused in a complex query with only a few values changing for each one for diff columns. The table has over 200 million rows. If I could use variable for concatenation of the three fields I could use them in a LIKE clause without having to copy and paste that whole thing each time because I have all of these also LIKE ('%2%') OR LIKE ('%3%') OR LIKE ('%4') OR LIKE ('%6%') and I can't seem to find a way to list all of those or make the code shorter. I ended up going with case statement also.

Comment: FYI the existing code I'm trying to fix for just this subquery is using 365 lines of code and is calculating every single value for either pos or neg or 0. Obviously it needs some advanced TLC and I appreciate the help from y'all so much!

Comment: Hey also, whoever created this original thing also didn't include an ID field, so matching up data is ridiculously difficult.

Comment: @BrendaStrong Well, there are always jobs like that, where there is a need to get something out of someone else's mess. But, on the other side, when there is a will - there is a way. I'm sure you can find your way. Glad to help, but with the infos that reached me I'm stuck. Try to think out of the box regarding lack of IDs - invent your own !!? You can do it.

Comment: @BrendaStrong Just posted a small addition...

Comment: You are right I didn't think about having a null in the middle column. Thank you!